# Google Embed Iframe shows full world map (not location)

Tags: google-maps

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d26008.43855814021!2d-78.795673!3d35.428672!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xf25f9e0e1fa54ed!2sLillington+Veterinary+Hospital!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1393359301118" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

I am using the above code to embed a google maps preview on a website.  But, the problem is, it is zooming all the way out to the entire world map when placing on website.  When I click preview embed size (custom size) on google maps when creating the map, it shows perfectly.

Screenshot included of how it is showing up on website located here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/issues-and-troubleshooting/maps/mac/chrome/KaQPRdnK4ZU

Am I doing something wrong?  I'm new to embedding google maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this seems to work:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?t=m&amp;hl=en-GB&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=35.432002,-78.795919&amp;spn=0.04336,0.084543&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=lyrftr:m,1091553228966483181,,&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?t=m&amp;hl=en-GB&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=embed&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=35.432002,-78.795919&amp;spn=0.04336,0.084543&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=lyrftr:m,1091553228966483181,,&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5zpd9/

On the [older version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkR3W.jpg) of Google Maps, has gives you the embed link when click the Chain Link icon:

[image]

Oh, and the [newer version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W12xa.jpg) can be linked by pressing 'Share and Embed map':

[image]

Which will show the newer version using:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d26008.454059026204!2d-78.795912!3d35.428624!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0xf25f9e0e1fa54ed!2sLillington+Veterinary+Hospital!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1393365205127" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5zpd9/1/

Comment: nevermind, found it.  Thank you for your help!  Works perfectly!

Comment: Just wanted to add comment since your post was updated that the newer version was zooming out for me nonstop.  It showed the entire world map when viewing with dimensions 450x200.  The older version was the one that worked perfectly the first time.  Personally, I think google should stick with the old format (where its not jumbled text that can't be read/edited).  The old version also allows you to enter custom variables such as zoom level.

Comment: thats genrally why i think ithe old one is better - the new one might still be in devlopment though.

Comment: More information on getting this working can be found in this thread: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/kcjwmB5XFx8

Comment: In case it isn't clear to some people how to switch back to the older (classic) version of Google Maps here's how: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3045828?hl=en